# "[object Window]" is showing in html when randomly positioning divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a site here http://msdhosting.co.uk/wp and I am trying to make a really cool effect on the header background image I have made.

What I would like is random dots to appear and then disappear again (like network pings) dotted around the map, as if it were monitoring something...

I have made this code, it nearly works, however the top value is not generated, and in stead prints.

```
<h1>Top:</h1>[object Window]".
```

Something really odd is happening and I can't work out what it is. Here's the code:

```
function placeimage(){
      $div = $('header');
      $body = $('body');
      left = Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt($div.innerWidth()));
      top = Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt($div.outerHeight()));
      $div.append('<h1>Top:'+top+'</h1><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="image" id="ping" onclick="doclick(this.id);" style="display: none; position: absolute;">');
      $img = $('#ping');
      $img.css('left',left+'px');
      $img.css('top',top+'px');
      $img.show();
      setTimeout(function(){hideimg();}, 5000);
      setTimeout(function(){placeimage();}, 3000);
}
function hideimg() {
    $img.remove();
}

placeimage();
```

Could anyone help me with this?

PS: The image used is just to test it!

Comment: `$div.append('<h1>Top:',top+'</h1>` – are you sure you want a comma there …?

Comment: Really, I don't need that printing part at all, I used it to show that the .innerHeight variable was not producing a value. Replacing the comma with a + fixed the formatting of the <h1> though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `top` is not declared as `var top` you are trying to concatenate window.top to an a string that gets resolved as the object window's string representation.

Declare all your variables with `var` and use the proper concatenation operator and you should see the problem go away.

When you declare variables in JavaScript without `var` the `window` object gets the scope on the variable. When you use `var` to declare a variable inside a function that variable now is only visible to the function.

You absolutely need to declare all variables in JavaScript with `var` other wise your program will become nightmarish.

example http://jsfiddle.net/rQw9y/:

```
function foo() {
    x = 5;
    setTimeout(function () {
         alert(x);
    }, 5000);
}

function bar() {
    x = 'I change window.x this includes the one in the foo function';
}

foo(); // in 5 seconds alert will read "I change window.x this includes the one in the foo function"
bar();
```

This problem is easily fixed by declaring `x` in both function with `var`

http://jsfiddle.net/rQw9y/2/

Comment: Thanks for the head's up, but i'm afraid I really don't understand that. Could you do one and I can copy it? Thanks!

Comment: I understand now! Thank's a lot, you've got it working for me!